# Test result - className not updated

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I'm unit testing in React (Jest, Enzyme). I expect #mail to have class 'solutions__mail-input', when input is changed, but it doesn't. Code:

```
inputEmail.simulate("change", {
      target: { value: "test@test.com", name: "mail" },
    });
```

then:

```
expect(solutions.find("#mail").hasClass("solutions__mail-input")).toEqual(
      true
    );
```

And it is not greened, value of input is changed, logic of changing class is also good.

Test:

```
  it("test valid mail", () => {
    const solutions = shallow(<Solutions />);
    const inputEmail = solutions.find("#mail");
    inputEmail.simulate("change", {
      target: { value: "test@test.com", name: "mail" },
    });
    expect(solutions.find("#mail").props().value).toBe("test@test.com");
    expect(solutions.find("#mail").hasClass("solutions__mail-input")).toEqual(
      true
    );
  });
```

Component:

```
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={mail}
        id="mail"
        name="mail"
        className={`solutions__mail-input${!readyToSend ? "--invalid" : ""}`}
        onChange={(e) => {
          changeMail(e.target.value);
          validateMail();
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything correct except `readyToSend` value. As `input` className is dependent on that, you have to verify its value first.

I have tried the below code with `readyToSend` as true and the unit tests are passing.

```
function MyComponent() {

  const [readyToSend, setReadyToSend] = useState(true);
  const [mail, setMail] = useState('');

  const changeMail = (value) => {
    setMail(value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={mail}
        id="mail"
        name="mail"
        className={`solutions__mail-input${!readyToSend ? "--invalid" : ""}`}
        onChange={(e) => {
          changeMail(e.target.value);
          // validateMail();
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

If you don't want to validate the value of `readyToSend`, use the below statement.

```
  expect(solutions.find("#mail").props().className.includes("solutions__mail-input"))
 .toEqual(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you are changing the value of `readyToSend` but what i can suggest is that since you will get `"solutions__mail-input"` only when `readyToSend` is true ,so while testing you need to make sure that the value of readyToSend is being changed to true.